# how to display ipynb notebook file in bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket, jupyter-notebook

Bit-bucket displays my notebook in a raw Json text form. I'd like it to be able to render a jupyter notebook for my collaborators

Anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-10507 says that as from versio 7.7 it is render automatically by default

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found a solution from Bitbucket dev post:

- To install the addon, click your avatar in the lower left corner and select "Integrations".
- You should now see "Bitbucket Notebook Viewer" listed in the addon listings.
- Once you have installed the addon you will get the option to render as a notebook on any file with the extension ".ipynb".

For team project repo, it should be installed under team account.

Comment: This addon doesn't open the internally referenced links. I get a page not found if I want to open a link from another page.

Comment: as of Feb 2024, the menu to activate the viewer is: (1) right up corner (settings) --> (2) Marketplace --> (3) select "IPython Notebook Viewer"

Answer (score 26):

As of 11/2018, this has moved. Click on your Avatar then Bitbucket Settings then Marketplace. You can search for or scroll down to the Notebook Viewer by Atlassian add-on and install it.

If you then go back to the .ipynb file, you will see a drop-down menu at the top that says "Default File Viewer". "Ipython Notebook" will appear as an option after you install the Notebook Viewer add-on and refresh. You can then toggle between the raw JSON and the Notebook views.

Comment: This functionality is gone now. see https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-10507

Answer (score 14):

As of 2021/Feb
I believe it's now under setting -> marketplace, look for the app call notebook viewer
[image]

after installed and access granted, you can switch view mode for the ipython code
[image]