# Jupyter notebooks + pull requests in bitbucket

Tags: git, jupyter-notebook, bitbucket

Can anyone here share some recommendations and best practices for working with Jupyter notebooks and Bitbucket/git? We have the Notebook viewer plugin installed, which allows us to view the notebooks.

However, we still have troubles in pull requests. It shows the raw JSON. We'd be happy to receive recommendations.

Comment: Would an addon help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53255059/6309

Comment: This addon (notebook viewer) helps in viewing a file. But still when viewing PRs we see the raw json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the output does not have to be reviewed (say, you will use the notebook as a template), then jupytext is your best option: https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext. It will allow you to transparently open several formats (py, md, etc) as Jupyter notebooks. Users will work with them as they now do but your pull request will do diffs on text files, not JSON.

If you want to keep the ipynb format, there is an official tool to run diffs on notebooks called nbdime (https://github.com/jupyter/nbdime). You can integrate nbdime with the git CLI.

Comment: Thanks. We now treat notebooks as immutable meaning we just dump then in the codebase for reference but refrain from changing them. But using jupytext sounds legit, might try it sometime

Answer (score 0):

Several options -

- [nbdime](https://github.com/jupyter/nbdime) for local diff & merge
- [jupytext](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext) for 2-way sync betweeb .ipynb & .py / .md
- [ReviewNB](https://www.reviewnb.com/) for reviewing notebook pull requests on GitHub & Bitbucket